# Not returning any values

Tags: python-3.x

```
def pal(n):
    if n[0]==n[len(n)-1] and len(n)!=1:
        pal(n[1:len(n)-1])
    elif(len(n)==1):
        return True
    else: 
        print("Not a Palindrome")
if pal("madam"):
    print("Yes, It is a Palindrome")
```

> I have tried to return value as "True" to print if statement. what is the issue with the program?

Comment: unless your program takes the code path with the `return` your method implicitly returns `None`. Did you want to add a `return` in front of your recursive call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this, you need to return your recursive function. There is also a little mistake, you check for `len == 1`, this won't always work when it has an even number of characters.

```py
def pal(n):
    if len(n) <= 1:
        return True

    if n[0] == n[-1]:
        return pal(n[1:-1])
    
    return False

if pal("madam"):
    print("Yes, It is a Palindrome")
else:
    print("No, It is not a Palindrome")
```